# Could not find property 'android' on root project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

i want to switch my project from eclipse to android studio with gradle support and get this failure message

> Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
>   Could not find property 'android' on root project 'Test'.

Could you help me?
I have a project with a few sublibraries

This is my top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: android


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

compile project('Test')
```

Comment: Did you add the 'java' plugin before your 'appengine' plugin?

Comment: did you really put `apply plugin: android` ? it's supposed to be `apply plugin: 'android'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put this in your top-level build file:

```
apply plugin: android
```

or this:

```
compile project('Test')
```

The `apply plugin` statement isn't necessary because there's no Android module in the root-level directory of projects with multi-module structure (which is the case for your project). And if you have dependencies, they need to go in a `dependencies` block in your module's build file.

Comment: Thanks i removed it already. 
Now i have this error 
Error:Execution failed for task ':zXing:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.