# Could not find method android() in root of multimodule project

Tags: android, build, gradle, multi-module

When trying to add parallel build for set of Android projects

For root `build.gradle` I added [from template](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.editors.gradle/docs/android/build.gradle)

```
subprojects {
    android{
        //{ for classic Android Eclipse project
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
            androidTest.setRoot('tests')

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
        //}
    }
}
```

But got error `Could not find method android() ...`

```
14:14:57.016 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:14:57.016 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:14:57.017 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
14:14:57.017 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file 'D:\Workspaces\ws\project\src\build.gradle' line: 21
14:14:57.017 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:14:57.017 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:14:57.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'src'.
14:14:57.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not find method android() for arguments [build_rp8mi2jisvr8vhjtgpkks742o$_run_closure1_closure2@6f762bb] on root project 'src'.
14:14:57.018 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Do I have to copy-paste such configuration in every module?
**Is there way to configure set of android project from one root `build.gradle`?**

Similar to [Could not find property 'android' on root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390270/could-not-find-property-android-on-root-project) there is no code at root level.

Used versions:

```
>gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to apply the `android` plugin inside `subprojects`.

Comment: can you please share process to add the android plugin