# Gradle build for set of Android projects (including libraries)

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, multi-module

I have 2 Android apps with 5 Android modules (Android library project). Total 7 Eclipse projects. I want to enable Gradle build for them. I added `build.gradle` in the root folder and listed all project in `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app1'
include ':app2'
...
```

However I discovered that I need to copy-paste section below in every one of 7 project

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
        ... // and so on like source folders configuration
}
```

Reason: when I add `apply plugin: 'android'` inside root `build.gradle`
(see [Could not find method android() in root of multimodule project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864068/could-not-find-method-android-in-root-of-multimodule-project)),
then I can't `apply plugin: 'android-library'` for libraries projects (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864292/minimal-gradle-configuration-for-android-library-in-multimodule-project)

But it is what I want to avoid, having different version of Android and Android tools specified in different places.

**How can I minify this configuration to have as many things as possible in one `build.gradle` config file.**

Comment: This should be one question, not three. Why can't you simply use `apply plugin: "android-library"` in the root build script's `subprojects` block?

Comment: There are not only libraries but 2 apps that use those libraries.
The answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864068/could-not-find-method-android-in-root-of-multimodule-project does not work for general case, that this 3rd question is.

Comment: Then either add some logic to the root script to apply the right plugin to each subproject (there are different ways to do this), or move the common parts into a script named `android.gradle` and apply that script to each subproject after applying the correct plugin for that project (all in the subproject's build script).

Comment: That could be good answer. Just needs more details.

Comment: For more information, see the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the many samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use your `build.gradle` in root, or you can define some values in `gradle.properties` in root folder to achieve your scope.

For example:

root/`build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "19.0.3"
}
```

module/`build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
}
```

OR using properties

root/`gradle.properties`:

```
VERSION_NAME=1.0.1
VERSION_CODE=11
```

module/`build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be as Peter Niederwieser suggested

> either add some logic to the root script to apply the right plugin to each subproject (there are different ways to do this), or move the common parts into a script named `android.gradle` and apply that script to each subproject after applying the correct plugin for that project (all in the subproject's build script).

Related docs is [Chapter 56. Multi-project Builds](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)