# Gradle build is stricter that Eclipse ADT (e.g. Found item _ more than one time)

Tags: android, eclipse, build, gradle, enide

I am adding [second gradle build for Eclipse Android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864716/gradle-build-for-set-of-android-projects-including-libraries).

However I have to fix a lot of smaller issue as Gradle finds additional errors, that Eclipse build does not, like duplicate values:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':FunshionAndroid:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\Workspaces\Proj\AndroidApp\res\values-hdpi\dimens.xml: Error: Found item Dimension/tvname_textsize more than one time
```

As my first goal is to finish Gradle build first, **how to configure gradle not to validate projects** (stricter than Eclipse does)

Comment: Do you have a dimensions called `tvname_textsize` defined in values-hdpi\dimens.xml more than once?

Comment: Of course. And not only this duplicate, as the project is old and duplicates where not checked before. However after spending 30 minutes fixing those tiny issues, I raise question here on Stackoverflow as there should be way to make Gradle build be not stricter than ADT build

Comment: Eclipse and ANT builds checked for duplicates as far back as I can remember. How do you propose that the build tools reconcile the conflicting dimensions? Just randomly pick one dimension and use that one?

Comment: I have no proposals. What is dimension here? Please add answer with some details.

Comment: I don't have an answer because I'm not sure it's possible. When I say conflicting dimensions I am referring to the duplicate items in your dimens.xml files. If I define a dimension called `item_width` twice in the same file with two different values, I *want* the build tools to complain instead of just picking one.

Comment: Not possible is also answer. I agree that checking duplicates during build is better. The problem is to get build similar with Eclipse ADT. (Or ADT similar with gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally there is Lint configuration. So the reason of errors was that Lint is enabled by default for release build (and gradle makes debug and release 2 builds by default)

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

or use `gradle assembleDebug` debug build only.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Which file did you place these options in?

Comment: You definitely need to learn more of Gradle first. That piece of code should go to every `build.gradle` that applies android plugin (when needed)