# Gradle build VS eclipse build

Tags: android, eclipse, build, gradle

I have a problem with a build for one specific application with gradle. The application can be compile and build with eclipse and it works well on the tablet. When I try to build it with Gradle I get error in the "compileDebugJava" part. I get this error

"error: cyclic inheritance involving class1
public class class1 implements class2"

I get a bunch of other error after this one but this is the one on the top. My project is depending on another one and this another is depending on a nother one. I just don't know why it works in eclipse but not with Gradle.

Comment: Can you post more details from the error logs?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same classpath in Eclipse and Gradle?

Comment: I don't know how to set up the classpath with gradle. Because with another project that only have one depencie, it work fine, but with this one it's all broke. The other project depend on appcompat_v7.

Comment: It seem's like eclipse is more permissive then gradle with some code error. I found the problem in compileDebugJava and it was really a code error that eclipse just ignore, now I have another one in dexDebug

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946772/gradle-build-is-stricter-that-eclipse-adt-e-g-found-item-more-than-one-time

Comment: If you chrck carefully, this question was asked before the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it. It appears that Eclipse is more permissive than gradle on the build system. There really was a cyclic inheritance in the code that needed to be fixed. I don't know how, but eclipse allow it. After fixing the code, all was fine with a clean build.